# Laptop suspend not working with open source drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, suspend, nouveau

I have trouble with the suspend feature on my laptop when using the open source drivers that Ubuntu installs. When I close the lid (or suspend manually from the top-right menu) the laptop screen locks up and goes to the login page, but there's nothing I  can do anything to get out of that state, be it mouse or keyboard input. The only way out for me is to forcibly shut down the laptop by holding the power key.

I tried multiple solutions and was able to get the suspend feature to work after switching to NVidia drivers, but that causes other issues, like the screen going black after login for many seconds and occasional tearing, so I would prefer if there is a way to get everything working with open source drivers.

Here are the details regarding my setup, if there's any info that's missing from the post and would be useful in resolution, do let me know and I'll share it.

HP VICTUS 16 (4H2B4EA#ABU)
Ryzen 7 5800H
NVidia 3060
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: I just got a blank screen, but the new update to 5.13.0-27-generic (upgrade/update normally ) seems to have got me suspend, but I do get a blank screen still and need to crtl-click mouse left button to resume.

Comment: I'm sticking with the NVidia drivers for now, the latest ones (don't remember the number off the top of my head, but it was probably 490 or 495). I haven't noticed any tearing so far and I also don't get the blank screen at login as I did with previous versions. The only downside is NVidia control panel is horribly implemented and is always a small, empty window when opened.